# Why are direct stresses at crack surface non-zero, but shear stresses are zero?

Tags: materials, material-science

I'm studying ceramics, more specifically, modelling failure intensity under compression.
Apparently, the shear stresses at crack surfaces are 0 because they are a free surface. However I don't see how you cannot use the same logic to argue that the direct stresses are also 0?